# PHP CSV Upload to MySQL Not Doing Anything

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I wrote a script to download a google sheet, and then upload this sheet to my dadabase.

Everything seems to be working fine except that the data is now being uploaded to my database.

I navigated to the folder and then ran this command:

```
php -f updatedatabase.php
```

This is the script I wrote (the googel sheet key is filled in with the actual key--i tested the link and it is working, and the database credentials have been starred out for security reasons):

```
<?php
    $datas = file_get_contents("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fOe2fz8PmYzTWU7l_KboHdv0zP0KZkhcJUTGJDUXaKk/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=All%20Items&range=A:G");
    $datas = explode( PHP_EOL, $datas );
    //FORMAT ("Name1", "Image1", "Description1", "Rarity1", "Price1", "Status1", "Store1"), ("Name2", "Image2", "Description2", "Rarity2", "Price2", "Status2", "Store2").....

    // Info to connect to the database
        $servername = ".com";
        $dbusername = "";
        $password = "!19";
        $dbname = "";

        $con=mysqli_connect( $servername, $dbusername, $password, $dbname );

    mysqli_query( $con, "TRUNCATE TABLE Items" );

    foreach ( $datas as $data ) {
        echo $data . "\n";
        mysqli_query( $con, "INSERT INTO Items (Name,Image,Description,Rarity,Price,Status,Store) VALUES " . $data );
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the log?

Comment: Do you mean my php error log or the output from running the script? Because honestly I can't find the error logs...

Comment: Please try https://www.godaddy.com/help/working-with-error-logs-1197

Comment: I did that and I don't have the account level necessary. I have the error logs though. It seems that there was an unexpected EOF. Thanks I should have thought of that in the first place. I was expecting errors to be output to the console like ubuntu

Comment: Okay it doens't seem to like me using the $data returned from downloading the CSV as the file to upload.

Comment: I changed my sql insert and it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: I'm checking it, please hide your database information for security

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178288/discussion-between-jared-chu-and-lucyturtle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` string is not well formated:

```
$csvData = file_get_contents("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fOe2fz8PmYzTWU7l_KboHdv0zP0KZkhcJUTGJDUXaKk/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=All%20Items&range=A:G");
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
}

// format the data string
// work with PHP7.0 or later
$datas = array_map(function ($data) {
    $dataString = implode("','", $data);
    return "('$dataString')";
}, $array);

// remove the head line
array_shift($datas);

// Info to connect to the database
$servername = "192.168.10.10";
$dbusername = "homestead";
$password = "secret";
$dbname = "gooledoc";

$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbusername, $password, $dbname);

mysqli_query($con, "TRUNCATE TABLE Items");

foreach ($datas as $data) {
    echo $data . "\n";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `Items` (`Name`,`Image`,`Description`,`Rarity`,`Price`,`Status`,`Store`) VALUES " . $data);
    var_dump($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
```